# Move a string in vs2012

Tags: c++, string, c++11, move

```
std::string t1("aaa");
const char *p = t1.c_str();
std::string t2(std::move(t1));
if (p == t2.c_str()) {
    std::cout << "ok!" << std::endl;    
}
```

This code printed nothing in vs2012. It just use `memmove` internally to copy the string in `t1` to `t2`. Why?

Comment: What did you expect? Are you aware that you're comparing pointers?

Comment: I'd expect to print "ok". Which is what GCC does, for example. @QingYun does VS's string implementation have move constructor at all?

Comment: @jrok: The VS implementation has a small string optimization. The tiny string in this example fits inside the `std::string` object.

Answer (score 9):

Formally, as jrok has pointed out, what you are doing is
undefined behavior, so you have no right to complain, no matter
what the implementation does.  Practically, it will depend on
the implementation.  The standard doesn't require the move
constructors of `std::string` to do anything with regards to the
source string.  If the implementation uses the small string
optimization (as does VC++, for example), and the string is
small enough to qualify, then there's no way it can do anything
*but* memcpy the characters; they are in a `char[]` in the
string object itself.  A CoW implementation (like that in g++) might
not do anything different that what it does in the copy
constructor either, on the grounds that it's not worth the
bother; you won't really save much.  (But it might, since just
swapping the pointers would save a little.)

I just tried the same thing in VC++, but with a string of 100
characters.  It did the swap (and the two pointers were equal).
So the behavior of VC++ depends on whether the string is
small enough for the SSO to apply.  G++ swaps in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Visualtudio compares the length of the string before it really moves the pointer, by debugging into `std::move` code, it shows it **copies** the string of the length is under **16 bytes**

```
void _Assign_rv(_Myt&& _Right)
{   
   // assign by moving _Right
   if (_Right._Myres < this->_BUF_SIZE)  //_BUF_SIZE is 16, comment mine
       _Traits::move(this->_Bx._Buf, _Right._Bx._Buf,
       _Right._Mysize + 1);
   else
   {    // copy pointer
    this->_Getal().construct(&this->_Bx._Ptr, _Right._Bx._Ptr);
    _Right._Bx._Ptr = pointer();
    }
    this->_Mysize = _Right._Mysize;
    this->_Myres = _Right._Myres;
    _Right._Tidy();
}
```

Comment: If you're familiar with the algorithm used, you'd see that it is impossible for it to do anything else if this case.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically what's going on here is "small string optimization".

Visual C++'s STL (and many others) have "fat" `std::string` classes that can hold a small string internally with zero memory allocations required.  This is an optimization for some common use cases.

Even with `std::move`, since your string is small enough that it is store entirely inside the `std::string` itself and so must be copied.  If you tried with a larger string your code would probably work, though there's absolutely no guarantee that it will and you *should not* depend on that behavior.

Essentially think of a `std::string` in these implementations as being similar-ish to:

```
class string {
 // space for small strings; only used if _external is nullptr
 char  _local[16];
 // pointer to heap-allocated memory; if nullptr, the string is stored in _local
 char* _external;

 // stores a string using small-string optimization is appropriate
 void store(char* src) {
   if (std::strlen(src) < sizeof(_local)) {
     // small string, store in our local buffer and set _external to nullptr
     std::strcpy(_local, src);
     delete _external;
     _external = nullptr;
   } else if (src != _external) {
     // large string, allocate space in heap
     delete _external;
     _external = new char[std::strlen(src) + 1];
     std::strcpy(_external, src);
   }
 }

public:
 // assign a C string to this string
 string(char* src) : _external(nullptr) { store(src); }
 string& operator=(char* src) { store(src); return *this; }

 // be sure to properly use either _local or _external pointer
 char* c_str() { return _external ? _external : _local; }
 bool empty() const { return c_str()[0] == 0; }
};
```